# how to calculate the means of 100s of subgroups in excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with ~8000 records, there are ~400 unique identifiers (i.e. element 101, 102, 103....500) that I need to calculated means for.  Is there a simple way to calculate means on large datasets like this?? Or will I have to do =average('select column block') for each subgroup/unique identifier?

Many Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$8000,"=IDNUMBER",$B$1:$B$8000)
```

Where

Column A is your column of ID numbers
Column B is your list that you need the mean from.

If your ID numbers are sequential, you can set up something like:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$8000,"="&100+row(A1),$B$1:B8000)
```

And copy that down from say C1 to C500

Alternatively you could make a list of the unique identifiers with another formula and place that unique list in C1 to C500 and then in column D use the following:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$A$8000,C1,$B$1:$B$8000)
```

If you have a header row you will need to adjust your ranges accordingly

The formula to generate a unique list of IDs is:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8001,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$8001),0,0),0))
```

Use that in column C but in row 2 and copy down.  So if your data starts in row 1 you will want to bump it down 1 row.

Comment: Or `SUMIF(...) / COUNTIF(...)` in older versions of Excel. Pretty sure `AVERAGEIF` was just introduced in Office 2010 or 2013.

Comment: Good answer but you should make your column A and B ranges absolute references if he is going to be dragging that formula down a column.

Comment: @mark abosulutely agree, I usually remember to make them absolute after I copy down the ranges and then start to wonder why things are going wonky on me!

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table with the unique identifiers in the rows and calculate the average of the values.

Answer (score 0):

For data that is clustered up nicely and immediately ready to be handed off for a visual review of the averages try a creating a Subtotal:

1. Select your data
2. Go to Data > subtotal (far right on the tab)
3. On the menu popup in the `At each change in` field, select the column header name that corresponds to your unique identifier.

[image: Subtotal Popup Screenshot]

4. Select Average for `Use function`. Select the checkbox of the column for which you want to find the group's mean.
5. Select other formatting features if desired (defaults typically work best)
6. Click okay.

Take a sip of coffee and let the magic happen.